# How to get the first nic as shown in IPConfig

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

A server I am testing on has 4 nics. What I need is a way in C# code to get the first NIC which I am told should be the first NIC that is shown when I run the command IPCONFIG.

I have the following code:

```
   public static IPAddress GetIPAddresses(string hostName, int index)
    {
        var entry= Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
        var addresses = new List<IPAddress>();

        for (int i = 0; i < entry.AddressList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (entry.AddressList[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                addresses.Add(entry.AddressList[i]);
        }
        return addresses.ToArray()[index];
    }
```

So if I pass in 0, I am hoping that this will be first NIC as in IPCONFIG. Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Your current code will give you back an IP address from whatever lookup mechanism that will be used (e.g. DNS/Wins/host file) for the given hostname, which can be rather random. It'll work only if each NIC has only 1 IP address, and the hostname maps to only that one IP address. Perhaps you need to enumerate the NICs as e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677815/c-sharp-network-adapters-list

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I filter only on ip4 addresses, would this mean the first one is first in the IPCONFIG list?

Comment: The same would apply if you do that.

Comment: Sames as in "could be rather random" as you mentioned above? If so, how do I get the first IPCONFIG nic?

Comment: What I should have wrote, I used NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() and filtered out ipv4 addresses. Would this work? Also my there can be only one IP address per NIC, so do I have to still worry about the lookup mechanism?

Comment: well, we don't know how microsoft coded the ipconfig tool, so that's rather hard to tell - you could test it empirically by comparing your output to ipconfig on different machines. NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() is likely your best bet so far. A NIC in general can certainly have more than 1 IP address though that might not be relevant for your particular case.