# Access network card power management properties

Tags: c#

Is there a way to access a list of network adapters, check if they have power management options, then change those options.

Example: Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power?

I need to check if the above option is turned on, if so turn it off?

Need a solution or multiple solutions that will work with Windows XP - Win8.1

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, you have to:

- [Get network adapters list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677815/c-sharp-network-adapters-list)
- Get according options from system registry: [Adjusting Power Settings in Windows XP SP3 via Registry](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dfe9e5eb-02fe-4391-a619-e4d067f712f8/adjusting-power-settings-in-windows-xp-sp3-via-registry?forum=itproxpsp).
- Change them in appropriate order: [How to: Create a Key In the Registry (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx).